# How to find all references to a function in VSCode?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, visual-studio-code

Admittedly, a very simple question...

What are some or all ways of being able to check for function usages/ calls/ invocations in `Visual Studio Code`?

For example (Python), `function_A()` usages include `function_B`:

```py
def function_A():
    print("Hello World!")

def function_B():
    function_A()

function_B()
>>> Hello World!
```

Comment: Either or. I just want to be able to see a list of all calls being made for any given function @rioV8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, it's impossible for now.

> We think there isn't an enough widespread need for this to warrant the
> maintenance cost for the feature.

You can refer to [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/14788) and [here](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/115)